# confirmation dialog isn't showing

Tags: javascript, confirm

```
document.querySelector('#select').addEventListener("change", function() {
    var confirm = confirm("Do you want to update data?");
    if (confirm == true) {
          if (this.value == "1") {
            $.ajax({
                        url: "update.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {
                            id: <?php echo $row['serial']?>,
                            type: "pending"         
                        },
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(dataResult){
                            var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
                            if(dataResult.statusCode==200){
                                alert("Successfully updated");

                                location.replace("../deposit/");
                            }
                            else if(dataResult.statusCode==201){
                                alert("Something went wrong");

                            }else{
                                alert("Everything went wrong");
                            }
                            
                        }
            });
          }else if(this.value == "2"){
            $.ajax({
                        url: "update.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {
                            id: <?php echo $row['serial']?>,
                            type: "succeed"         
                        },
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(dataResult){
                            var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
                            if(dataResult.statusCode==200){
                                alert("Successfully updated");

                                location.replace("../deposit/");
                            }
                            else if(dataResult.statusCode==201){
                                alert("Something went wrong");

                            }else{
                                alert("Everything went wrong");
                            }
                            
                        }
            });
          }else if(this.value=="3"){
            $.ajax({
                        url: "update.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {
                            id: <?php echo $row['serial']?>,
                            type: "canceled"            
                        },
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(dataResult){
                            var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
                            if(dataResult.statusCode==200){
                                alert("Successfully updated");

                                location.replace("../deposit/");
                            }
                            else if(dataResult.statusCode==201){
                                alert("Something went wrong");

                            }else{
                                alert("Everything went wrong");
                            }
                            
                        }
            });
          }else{
            console.log("Update canceled");
          }


}
});
```

I added a confirmation dialog while user changes `option`. When I run the code, and changed `option` I am not getting any confirmation dialog but, when I was working without confirmation dialog everything was working fine. Why it's happening? I got error in console `Uncaught TypeError: confirm is not a function at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous>` [I was looking at w3schools courses but, i am unable to understand anything](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp)

Comment: Don't use `confirm` as a variable name.

Comment: @connexo Working... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid using the name of HTML and Window objects and properties:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

> don't use confirm use ConfirmDialog or something!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.confirm` as it is a global function exposed to Window.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm

---

You can also change your code to just this (you don't need the `var confirm`. This is also the issue, since you use `confirm` twice, but for different purposes.

```
    if (confirm("Do you want to update data?")) {
```

If you do want the variable, use the standard naming convention for booleans, which is to add "is", "has","can" or "should" before the variable name:

```
    var hasConfirmed = confirm("Do you want to update data?");
    if (hasConfirmed == true) {
```